# Using XPath to get strings between and inside tags

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

Super new to XPath so forgive me if I stumble through terms. I'm using `IMPORTXML()` in a google doc in order to pull info from a webpage. Basically what I'm shooting for is to turn this

[image]

into

[image]

What I can't figure out is how to pull info between the `<br>` nodes and pull the string from within the `<a>` node. 
I've fumbled my way as far as `=IMPORTXML($A$1, "//p/b[starts-with(text(), '"& $A4 &"')]/following-sibling::text()[1]")` to get a return of 1 for Casting Time, but not any further.

The end goal is to do this for about a dozen different values across the page and cycle the checks through about 500 web pages, hence the cells in the formula. Any help would be appreciated.

---

Super in depth clarification section

Using XPath and a Google Sheet I am attempting to automatically make a roll20 formatted template macro for each spell on a spell casters list. 
For example, the [Shaman Spell List](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/spell-lists-and-domains/shaman) I used `//tr/td[1]/a[@href]` and `//tr/td[1]/a/@href` to create side by side columns of spell names and their associated URL's. [image]
Then on another page I can copy and paste the entire class spell list and use `Vlookup` to get the associated URL's while keeping the organized level sectioned tables like so (Note the Hyperlinked spell names are rich text so the internal URL is invisible to `IMPORTXML`, hence the extra step). [image]

With a single class having upwards of 500+ spells the ultimate goal is to create a series of `IMPORTXML` that look at the spell URL and pull relevant data from this particular section. For this example I'm using [Arcane Mark](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/arcane-mark).

[image]

The final goal is to use `IMPORTXML` to get each important category such as School, Casting Time, Target, Effect, Area, Range, etc. Put them in their respective columns and have a Concatenate I've written go through and pull all the various parts into one big formatted string compatible with the roll20 macro template to look like `&{template:default} {{Name=Arcane mark}} {{School=Universal}} {{Casting Time=1 Standard Action}} {{Components=V,S}} {{Range=Touch}} {{Effect=One personal rune or mark, all of which must fit within 1 sq. ft.}} {{Duration=Permanent}} {{Saving Throw=None}} {{Spell Resistance=No}}`

Comment: it's not clear what exactly you want to scrape, explain pls

Comment: You'll need to post the url or at least the related code.

Comment: Besides the need for clarifications, do note that XPath 1.0 selects nodes from a document tree and then there is no notion of **tag**.

Comment: The following XPath would be an example of how you could pull '1 standard action' from the input `concat(//p[b[text()='Casting Time']]/text()[2], //p[b[text()='Casting Time']]/a)`. But I think we need a bit more clarity to help with the bigger issue

Comment: Unfortunately the full scope of this project was something that was not able to be completed inside of the limits of a google sheet. I eventually wound up completing the task utilizing a different, more organized, website and external Python code exporting into a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
 IMPORTDATA("http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/arcane-mark"),1000,5), 
 "where Col1 contains 'School'", 0)),,999^99)), A10&"\</b>\ (.+)\;"))
```

[image: 0]